# Incrementation in Lua

Tags: lua

I am playing a little bit with Lua.

I came across the following code snippet that have an unexpected behavior:

```c
a = 3;
b = 5;
c = a-- * b++; // some computation
print(a, b, c);
```

Lua runs the program without any error but does not print `2  6  15` as expected. Why ?

Comment: how do you run it? I get `3 5 3` as expected (as -- starts a comment) using Lua 5.1.4.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

[`--` starts a single line comment](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Lua_Programming/How_to_Lua/comment), like `#` or `//` in other languages.

So it's equivalent to:

```
a = 3;
b = 5;
c = a
```

Answer (score 18):

Lua doesn't increment and decrement with `++` and `--`.  `--` will instead start a comment.

Comment: True, but this doesn't explain why the program compiles and runs.

Comment: It compiles and runs because LUA does not mind missing semicolons at the end of lines. It will just print out 3 5 3.

Comment: @annih It does make sense why this code compiles, as said on this answer -- starts a comment, so essentialy your code is: `a = 3; b = 5; c = a;` Note that ; is necessary on top of my head if you do it all in one line, like I do

Answer (score 13):

There isn't and `--` and `++` in lua.
so you have to use `a = a + 1` or `a = a -1` or something like that

Answer (score 4):

If you want `2  6  15` as the output, try this code:

```
a = 3
b = 5
c = a * b
a = a - 1
b = b + 1
print(a, b, c)
```

Answer (score 3):

This will give

```
3 5 3
```

because the 3rd line will be evaluated as `c = a`.

Why? Because in Lua, comments starts with `--`. Therefore, `c = a-- * b++; // some computation` is evaluated as two parts:

1. expression: `c = a`
2. comment: `* b++; //// some computation`

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems in your Lua code:

```lua
a = 3;
b = 5;
c = a-- * b++; // some computation
print(a, b, c);
```

One, Lua does not currently support incrementation. A way to do this is:

```lua
c = a - 1 * b + 1
print(a, b, c)
```

Two, `--` in Lua is a comment, so using `a--` just translates to `a`, and the comment is `* b++; // some computation`.

Three, `//` does not work in Lua, use `--` for comments.

Also it's optional to use `;` at the end of every line.

Answer (score -2):

**EDIT:** Using SharpLua in C# incrementing/decrementing in lua can be done in shorthand like so:

```
a+=1 --increment by some value
a-=1 --decrement by some value
```

In addition, multiplication/division can be done like so:

```
a*=2 --multiply by some value
a/=2 --divide by some value
```

The same method can be used if adding, subtracting, multiplying or dividing one variable by another, like so:

```
a+=b
a-=b
a/=b
a*=b
```

This is much simpler and tidier and I think a lot less complicated, but not everybody will share my view.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Those operators like `+=` do not exist in Lua, even in the latest work version Lua 5.4!

Comment: @prapin I've been using said operators for about 2 months now, tested and working... so, either they're not documented or my lua scripts are 'magically' interpreting said operators and doing exactly what I expect them to do. I suggest you do some of your own testing before dismissing my solution right off the bat.

Comment: I was surprised, so I did test on a raw Lua 5.3 interpreter, and I also checked in the documentation in case it would be a new feature in 5.4 that I didn't know about. I suspect that you are using a _modified_ version of the Lua interpreter (which one?)

Comment: @prapin I'm using SharpLua as parser within C# which probably then has support for the shorthand operators built in, so technically then it wouldn't work with the vanilla interpreter. Would be great if it could be made a standard feature - would certainly tidy things up a bit! So yeah, I suppose technically it doesn't work 'out of the box'.

Answer (score -2):

You can do the following:

```
local default = 0
local max = 100

while default < max do
     default = default + 1
     print(default)
end
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.